# React Native Gradle: which debug.keystore file is my project using?

Tags: gradle, react-native

In my React Native project, I have `<project root>/android/app/debug.keystore` and `HOME/.android/debug.keystore`. How do I figure out which one my project is using?

Answer (score 0):

By default in my all code I have seen that it uses android/debug.keystore
But As i recall there is a file that have all credentials for which keystore file to use with password and all while generating debug apk